Cannot discover a Tuya powered bluetooth device using Tuya Smart Life app SDK in a React Native environment
I am having some trouble using Tuya Smart Life app SDK in my React Native application.
I am using this library to bridge between Tuya's native SDK and React Native.
Using the SDK I successfully created a user, a home and then started the bluetooth scan,
in the logs i can see that is discovers my device.
After following Tuya Docs i see the discovered device should be returned from the "didDiscoveryDeviceWithDeviceInfo" but it doesn't happen for me.
Not sure if its connected but in the logs i see this:
[ThingRequest] request: domain = a1-us.iotbing.com, url = https://
a1-us.iotbing.com/api.json, api =
smartlife.m.device.bind.status.get, commonParams = {
  "lang" : "en",
  "bizData" : "{\"nd\":1,\"customDomainSupport\":\"1\"}",
  "deviceId" : "229A6B7E-D000-46B5-96F7-8FA1D39246F2",
  "et" : "0.0.2",
  "osSystem" : "17.4.1",
  "bundleId" : "com.loopump.app",
  "time" : "1715584371",
  "lon" : 0,
  "channel" : "sdk",
  "nd" : 1,
  "appVersion" : "1.0.0",
  "ttid" : "appstore_d",
"os" : "IOS",
  "v" : "1.1",
  "sid" :
"az171557r6264723dJPjtCF38dfad8b6ed4cd012febe985129302799",
  "sign" :
"e48995f2513ccefae9936cfe387f3cb100606a3e22bd7a02f07aa6c424dd6f32"
,
  "platform" : "iPhone 13",
  "requestId" : "326662BA-85AC-4C63-A94B-7D7E77D70E57",
  "sdkVersion" : "5.2.0",
  "timeZoneId" : "Asia\/Manila",
  "lat" : 0,
  "clientId" : "nwvrfnnvnd5kxvrss55x",
  "deviceCoreVersion" : "5.7.0",
  "a" : "smartlife.m.device.bind.status.get",
  "cp" : "gzip"
}, businessParams = {
  "encryptValue" : "4A536DA0ECEBAEE5",
  <...>

[ThingRequest] response: api = smartlife.m.device.bind.status.get,
data = {
  "success" : false,
  "errorCode" : "PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "status" : "error",
  "errorMsg" : "No access",
  "t" : 1715584370720
}

The device id here is not of the bluetooth device i am trying to pair but its the actual Iphone that is scanning for devices.
This is the Objective-C code that starts the scan and should return the discovered device:
static TuyaBLERNScannerModule * scannerInstance = nil;

@interface TuyaBLERNScannerModule()<ThingSmartBLEManagerDelegate>

@property(copy, nonatomic) RCTPromiseResolveBlock promiseResolveBlock;
@property(copy, nonatomic) RCTPromiseRejectBlock promiseRejectBlock;

@end

@implementation TuyaBLERNScannerModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(TuyaBLEScannerModule)

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startBluetoothScan:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolver rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)rejecter) {
  if (scannerInstance == nil) {
    scannerInstance = [TuyaBLERNScannerModule new];
  }
  NSLog(@"DEBUG: startBluetoothScan");
  [ThingSmartBLEManager sharedInstance].delegate = scannerInstance;
  scannerInstance.promiseResolveBlock = resolver;
  scannerInstance.promiseRejectBlock = rejecter;

  [[ThingSmartBLEManager sharedInstance] startListening:YES];
}

- (void)didDiscoveryDeviceWithDeviceInfo:(ThingBLEAdvModel *)deviceInfo {
  // print device info
  NSLog(@"DEBUG: %@", [deviceInfo yy_modelToJSONObject]);
  if (scannerInstance.promiseResolveBlock) {
    self.promiseResolveBlock([deviceInfo yy_modelToJSONObject]);
  }
}

@end

It never reaches the "didDiscoveryDeviceWithDeviceInfo", the logs never logs.
